# Quantile of function of random variable

Tags: data-transformation, quantiles

Given a continuous analytical function $g(x)$ of the continuous random variable $x$, the CDF and PDF $F_x(x),f_x(x)$ and the quantile function $F^{-1}_x(t)$ of $x$, is it possible to find a closed form expression for the quantile function $G^{-1}_g(t_g)$ of $g(x)$?

Specifically, I'm looking to express the quantile function in the case $g(x) = x^2$ in terms of the known functions of $x$.

Comment: Hint: Write $\Pr(g(X) \le t)$ in terms of $F(x) = \Pr(X\le x)$.

Comment: In the case $g(x)$ is a strictly monotonic function I can always invert it to get a closed form solution for the quantile. For the case of $g(x) = x^2$ I'm still stuck with an equation I can't solve for the quantile: 
$F_x(q^{0.5})-F_x(-q^{0.5})=p$, where a solution for q is required.

Comment: Whether that has a closed-form solution depends both on the details of $F$ and what you consider "closed" to be.